# Usar wordpress para automatizar procesos

Tags: wordpress

es conveniente usar Wordpress para hacer páginas que hagan uso de CRUD y que automaticen procesos de un negocio, es que hasta ahora solo he visto que wordpress lo usan para la presentación del negocio y ventas, no se si me explico, agradezco sus opiniones.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español , da un [tour] y revisa [ask] . Tu pregunta se basa en puntos de vista, por lo cual es muy amplia y no será bien recibida.

Comment: Depende qué procesos quieras automatizar. Por ejemplo relación con clientes, replicar contenidos, pueden ser idóneos para WP.